# Show a warning message when you follow a link to a deleted answer or comment

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, posts

#### About:

When you follow a link to a comment or answer you might end-up being confused if the answer or comment is removed.

This little userscript shows a warning on top of the page when the link you just used contains a fragment to an answer or comment that no longer exists on the page.

*This is a repost of [my original answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251236/158100) on Meta Stack Exchange*

#### Screenshot:

Here is an [Animated GIF to show the script in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMtWC.gif)
<sup>*GIF kindly provided by user [41686d6564](https://stackapps.com/users/80115/41686d6564)*</sup>

#### Download / Install:

You can find it ready to be consumed by TamperMonkey or GreaseMonkey on the Github repository. Here is the [direct install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/CheckForExistingCorA.user.js) aand here it the [source](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/CheckForExistingCorA.user.js).

#### Platform:

The script will run on any browser that support userscripts with the general available userscript managers like Tampermonkey or GreaseMonkey.

#### Contact:

If you find a bug or have a feature request either create an [issue](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/issues) or leave a comment here.

Allow for 6 to 8 weeks before fixing.

#### License:

The code is released under the MIT License

#### Code:

The code is written in JavaScript and has a dependency on the jQuery loaded on the page by Stack Exchange.

For interested parties here is the full code:

```js
 // ==UserScript==
// @name         Check if comment and answer exist
// @namespace    http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      1.2
// @description  Show a message if the answer or comment in the hash of the url doesn't exist
// @author       rene
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        *://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match        *://askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match        *://mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @match        *://stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match        *://superuser.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function (document, window, StackExchange) {

    var hash = (window.location && window.location.hash)?window.location.hash:'';

    function showMessage(jqsel, text) {
        if (jqsel === null) {
            // wait for SE to be ready
            StackExchange.initialized.done(function() {
                var classid = 'missing-post-or-comment';
                // put a notify on top
                StackExchange.notify.show('The ' + text + ' is not found. It may have been deleted', classid);
                // remove it automagically after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () { StackExchange.notify.close(classid);}, 5000);
            });
        }
    }

    StackExchange.ready( function() {
        if (hash.length > 0) {
            cleanHash = hash.substring(1);
            if (cleanHash.indexOf('comment') === 0) {
                ids = cleanHash.substring(7).split('_');
                var lnk = document.getElementById('comments-link-' + ids[1]);
                if (lnk !== null) {
                    StackExchange.comments.loadAll(lnk).done(function() {
                        showMessage(document.getElementById('comment-'+ ids[0]), 'comment');
                    });
                } else {
                    showMessage(document.getElementById('comment-'+ ids[0]), 'comment');
                }
            // Make sure the hash is not the ID of the question.
            } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/questions/' + cleanHash) !== 0) {
                if (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(cleanHash, 10))) {
                    showMessage(document.getElementById('answer-' + cleanHash), 'answer');
                }
            }
        }
    });

}(document || unsafeWindow.document, window || unsafeWindow, StackExchange || unsafeWindow.StackExchange ));
```

Or find it in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/CheckForExistingCorA.user.js) where you're invited to submit pull requests.

Comment: That thumbnail tho.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not known for my artistic skills .. :(

Comment: we all know that flowers can't draw, @rene :/

Comment: Just used this recently and it's useful when fighting Smokey's posts! Just a small request, is it possible to show the message using `StackExchange.notify.show("message")` instead? Any opinion/reason?

Comment: @AndrewT. I just figured out how I can use that without sacrificing functionality. With you in the next 6 to 8 hours.

Comment: @AndrewT. the version which uses notify is now live in the github repo.